# Выборка записей с одинаковой датой в поле

Tags: sql, массивы, выборка, презентации

Есть таблица с полями

```
SNILS       COD   VisitDate
4521245     50    30.01.2005
4521245     51    29.01.2005
4521245     52    30.01.2005
4521245     50    28.01.2005

4521251     50    28.01.2005
4521232     19    28.01.2005
4521234     20    28.01.2005
```

Как сделать запрос, чтобы выбрать те записи, у которых в группе одного SNILS одинаковые даты (например, в группе СНИЛС 4521245 одинаковые даты 30.01.2005)?

Comment: А какая информация конкретно нужна. Показали исходные данные, хорошо, покажите еще что именно хотите увидеть в результате. И обязательно уточните какой именно у вас SQL, Возможно оконными функциями было бы легче решить, но не все СУБД их поддерживают

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить в конец запроса `GROUP BY SNILS, VisitDate`